# Disable/Pause RecyclerView animation and/or just allow RecyclerView animation when scrolling

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

So basically, i have a simple RecyclerView.Adapter and i have something like this:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    final Session currentSession = sessionList.get(position);

    viewHolder.textTittle.setText(currentSession.getTitle());
    viewHolder.textStartEnd.setText(currentSession.getStartHour() + " - " + currentSession.getEndHour());
    viewHolder.textDate.setText(currentSession.getDateFormatedString());
    viewHolder.textTrack.setText(currentSession.getTrack());
    viewHolder.textRoom.setText(currentSession.getRoom());


    if (position > this.lastPosition) {
        animate(viewHolder, true);
    } else {
        animate(viewHolder, false);
    }

    this.lastPosition = position;
    viewHolder.setClickListener(clickListener, currentSession);
}
```

The animations are fine when i scroll up/down but when i change all the data or even load the RecyclerView (contains a list of CardViews) the animations appear really messy.
I was trying disable the animations temporarily when im changing all the data or just enable it when im scrolling up the list of CardViews.

Do you have any idea how to do this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

RecyclerView has built in animation support but it does not support animating while scrolling yet.

Looks like you are animating them yourself, in that case (assuming you don't want add/remove/change animations) just set ItemAnimator to null. (`RecyclerView#setItemAnimator`).

These custom animations you add will cause problem in recycling so you should also implement `onFailedToRecycle`. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onFailedToRecycleView(VH)

Comment: So you sugest put ItemAnimator to null just when im changing the dataset to prevent the animations mess up or to set it premanently? In that case the animations i have at the moment will work? Thanks for the answer.